# Is there race condition when multiple Future/Timer complete simultaneously

Tags: dart, race-condition

Can there be a race condition if multiple Timer/Future complete simultaneously in Dart? For example, is there a race condition when accessing the `test` and `test` structures in the Timer complete handler in the following code?

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  Map<String, int> test = {};
  List<int> test2 = [];

  Timer t1 = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    test['a'] = 45;
    test2.add(1);
  });

  Timer t2 = Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    test['b'] = 67;
    test2.add(2);
  });

  Timer t3 = Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    print(test);
    print(test2);
  });
}
```

Or are Timer/Future completions processed synchronously by the main thread? Can the code within two callbacks be interwoven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Dart isolate executes code in a single thread.  Asynchronous code running in a single Dart isolate can run *concurrently* but not in *parallel*.

In general, if the callbacks themselves do asynchronous work, then they can be interleaved.  Any `await` (which is equivalent to any `Future.then()` callback) is a point where execution returns to the event loop, interrupting your asynchronous function.

In your particular example, your callbacks are fully synchronous and cannot be interrupted.  Your `Timer`s probably will fire in a defined order since events are added to FIFO queues.  However, that seems brittle, and I do not think that it would be a good idea to rely on callback ordering.

Also see: [Prevent concurrent access to the same data in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55699545/).